# How to filter an array of objects based on value

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects:

[image]

The object looks like this:

```
applicationNumber: "35028"
denomination: "ZippIT"
denominationNature: "Denomination"
denominationStatus: "SURRENDERED"
publicationCountry: "RU"
publicationType: "PBR"
speciesName: "Triticum aestivum L."
```

I want to be able to filter that array of objects based on a string. If that string is on any of the values of the object, we return the object.

Any idea on where to start from?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes

Comment: What about `const filteredArray = originalArray.filter(item => !Object.values(item).includes('yourstring'))`?

Comment: Yes, if any of them. And normally the keys are dynamic. So Giovanni's solution won't work for me...

Comment: @Sonhja I canceled but you didn't say that keys could be dynamic

Comment: @secan I think the OP want the string as a positive indicator to keep the object, so I think you don't need the `!` (which would exclude objects with that string); otherwise, looks like a solid solution

Comment: @apsillers, yes, you are right; I misread the question. Thanks for noticing it. So the actual solution would be `const filteredArray = originalArray.filter(item => Object.values(item).includes('yourstring'))`

Comment: With "dynamic" keys I mean that I never know the key as info comes from different places, so I cannot filter based on a known key name.
I'm trying the filtering now

Comment: It works perfect! Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you're looking for a combination of [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).

**Something like this:**

```js
let includesString = arrayOfObjs.filter(object => 
  Object.values(object).includes(targetString)
)
```

**Demo:**

```js
let arrayOfObjs = [
  {value1: "target", value2: "not a target"},
  {value3: "also not a target", value4: "target"},
  {value5: "nope"},
  {value6: "target"}
]

let objectsWithTargets = arrayOfObjs.filter(object => 
  Object.values(object).includes("target")
)

console.log(objectsWithTargets)
```